# Passing Parameters to uploadifyUpload method when start

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, uploadify

I have some code written in JS, i call following line in JS function and it works fine

```
$('#uploadify_1').uploadifyUpload();
```

Here is my php file, code

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
        $filenms = time().$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
        $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) .$filenms;

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo  $filenms;

}
```

I have var id=1; in JS file, I want to pass this variable to my php file, like this

```
 $('#uploadify_1').uploadifyUpload(id);
```

But it does not work. Please advice me, how can i pass that variable to same php file when it start uploading, so i use ID to update DB, in php file.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say RTM :P

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
   // Some options
   'method'   : 'post',
   'formData' : { 'id' : id }
});
```

Then in your PHP:

```
$_POST['id']
```

More: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/customizing-the-server-side-upload-script/

Comment: I use this code in place of $('#uploadify_1').uploadifyUpload(); but it does not start uploading !

Comment: Did you defined other important vars like:
 `'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
  'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'`
This is basic stuff.
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/implementing-uploadify/

Btw. i can't see such method like uploadifyUpload() in docs.